# Define variable accessible in all pages PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder how to define a variable that is accessible in all pages in PHP. In my case I need it because I have an application where a lot of queries on different pages depend on a round variable that increases each week.

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that I need to be able to define the variable in a class and use it in other classes in Laravel.

Comment: You can achieve this also using view composer. This article can lead you through creating view composer in Laravel: https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers

Comment: You can use global variables

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the baked in env library:

In your `.env` file define your key with the value:

```
MY_VARIABLE=some_value
```

You can now call this anywhere in your app:

```
<?php

    $my_variable = env('MY_VARIABLE');
```

You can also pass a second optional parameter in-case the env var is not given:

```
<?php

$my_variable = env('MY_VARIABLE', 'some_value');
```

Comment: The only issue i see here is if you are using version control like git and the variable is part of the app, then it will not be added, as the .env file is no included in version control for security reasons. So having to add details to the readme file to ensure they do add it etc

Comment: @SimonDavies can you describe the nature of the value of this variable? Where is it stored? DB? cache?

Answer (score 0):

in php, you should be able to use the `include "page.php";` method to include a php file on all your pages that contains the code for your variable.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a constants config file, and then call it form there.

So in the config folder create a file called: `constants.php`then add the following:

```
  <?php

    return [

        'VARIABLE_NAME' => 'VALUE',
   ];
```

This shoudl automatically get loaded once created.

To use call it like:

```
  $variable = config('constants.VARIABLE_NAME');
```